# Information on hover on image does not display with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I try to replicate this effect with Tailwind - https://codepen.io/kesavaraj/pen/QWWBwzR
And I transpiled the Css into tailwind, I believe correctly.

But still I dont achieve the hover effect, when I hover on the image. What did I wrong?

This is my code that I have written with Tailwind

```
  <body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="flex justify-center mt-20">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-8 sm:grid-cols-3">
          <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee-image">
              <img src="http://resources.panderasystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/slip-maan.png" class="w-full h-full object-cover" alt="employee-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="employee-details">
              <div class="employee-name text-center">
                <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">Benjamin<br><span class="employee-role">Developer</span></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="employee-social-link flex justify-center">
                <ul class="list-none">
                  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee-image">
              <img src="https://www.duraplas.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Smiling-young-casual-man-2.png" class="w-full h-full object-cover" alt="employee-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="employee-details">
              <div class="employee-name text-center">
                <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">Jackson<br><span class="employee-role">Designer</span></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="employee-social-link flex justify-center">
                <ul class="list-none">
                  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="employee">
            <div class="employee-image">
              <img src="http://www.pngonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Man-Business-Transparent-PNG.png" class="w-full h-full object-cover" alt="employee-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="employee-details">
              <div class="employee-name text-center">
                <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">Franklin<br><span class="employee-role">Tester</span></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="employee-social-link flex justify-center">
                <ul class="list-none">
                  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-behance" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you show us a functional snippet orchestrating the problem?

Comment: When you say "hover effect" do you mean when the image moves upwards? You haven't seemed to completely replicate the CodePen.

Comment: As already stated there's a bunch of custom CSS missing that relates to the hovering, transitions, etc. Nothing in the code you have here duplicates that functionality.